# Batch processing with ImageAlpha

Tags: macos, terminal, image-processing, imagealpha

I am trying to figure out how to do batch processing with [**ImageAlpha**](http://pngmini.com/). I really like this program, but I cannot figure out how to batch process. Just to be clear, I am trying to convert several images from PNG24 to PNG8.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, and is therefore [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to try [SU], but you will have to add a lot more detail than "cannot figure out how to do this" before reposting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/) site:

> **Batch processing** 
>   
> ImageAlpha is mostly based on pngquant. You'll find compiled **[pngquant](https://github.com/pornel/improved-pngquant#readme)** executable in ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources
>   directory.

e.g.

```
ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/pngquant -ext 8bit.png yourInputImage.png
```

For more options run:

```
ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/pngquant -h
```

Goodluck

Comment: Thank you for the help but my problem is that I don't know how to run the executable. I can get as far as opening the executable but then where to go from there I have no idea. When I open the pngquant executable it says "process completed logout" and I can't type anything more in that window.

Comment: You execute the application from Terminal. Run Terminal.app (from Applications/Utilities) and use the commands above. Note that you must either `cd` to the directory that contains ImageAlpha.app first or prepend the path...for example, if ImageAlpha.app is in /Applications, try this in Terminal: `/Applications/ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/pngquant -h`

Comment: It looks like you've never used the commandline before on osx. There are plenty of [tutorials](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/12/14/terminal_one.html) out there. The above will become trivial once you've understood the basics (navigating to a directory, running an application, using flags)

Comment: I tried doing all of the things that have been recommended and after I run the the executable I followed this tuturial <http://www.ethangardner.com/articles/alpha-transparency-in-png-8-images-without-using-fireworks/> and it keeps saying pngquant: command not found?

Comment: either it's a typo: should be pngquant, not ngquant, either you're trying to run the command from a path different from where pngquant lives. Note that the tutorial you've picked is for Windows and CommandPrompt uses different commands from Terminal (although a few are similar). Maybe it's easier to add pngquant to the system path so you can call the application from anywhere on the system. Try this in Terminal: `sudo pico ~/.bash_profile` - this should open a text editor. Add/Append this to the file export `PATH=/Applications/ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/:$PATH` then exit (Ctrl+X) & save

Comment: When you open a new Terminal session/tab you should be able to simply type: `pngquant -h` to see how to use the application's options/flags

Comment: So this is what I am doing. I open terminal and type /Applications/ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/pngquant -h Then hit enter and it says compiled so then I type  pngquant 256 /Users/Stephen/Desktop/Fire\ SD\ PNGs/fire_0.png. I got the path to my image by dragging it in to terminal, then I hit enter and it says -bash: pngquant: command not found?

Comment: Typing `/Applications/ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources/pngquant -h` once runs the application once. That doesn't mean you're in the the same folder with the application (which you can check by typing `pwd`). If you don't want to set add the application to PATH do this first: `cd /Applications/ImageAlpha.app/Contents/Resources` then feel free to call `pngquant` with the options you need. Either take the time to go through the basics or let's run a quick chat, otherwise these comments will drag to long

Comment: What do you mean by a quick chat?

Comment: Does this support wildcards?

Comment: haven't tried but hoping it would do. Not on a mac atm so can't test. even it it doesn't however, you should still be able to use a for loop in bash